# Casting to array of pointers in C99

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I'm currently writing a complex function that took me a great amount of time to conceive. This function uses an array of type: " struct foo* ", which was previously defined like this:

```
struct foo** array_of_pointers = NULL;
```

To make the code easier to understand, I decided to change the definition to:

```
struct foo* array_of_pointers[] = {NULL};
```

(The assignment is done to make it a strong symbol)

But now the problem is here:

```
array_of_pointers = (?) calloc(256, sizeof(struct foo*));
```

Intuitively I replaced " ? " with " struct foo* [ ] ". This looks weird and actually results in a compiler error: "cast specifies array type".

So my question is: Does anyone know what should be placed instead of " (?) " ?

Comment: `struct foo**`? An array is still a pointer...

Comment: [No need to cast the results of `malloc` and `calloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)

Comment: Also - I believe (could be wrong) that `sizeof *array_of_pointers` is preferable, but that may be stylistic.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are declaring an array of type `struct foo*` with a single element (because on unspecified size `[]`), and that element is `NULL`:

```
struct foo* array_of_pointers[] = {NULL};
```

The address it points to can't be changed, as in:

```
array_of_pointers = calloc(256, sizeof(struct foo*));  
// wrong, doesn't compile and casting the return of calloc won't help
```

It is not the same as when declaring a pointer to `struct foo*` , as here:

```
struct foo** array_of_pointers = NULL;
```

You can only assign to the latter.